# full path for open / openat relative filenames

Tags: ebpf, bcc-bpf

Using the [opensnoop.py](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/opensnoop.py#L230) from [iovisor/bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc.git), I'm trying to extend the ebpf code to handle extraction of full paths from a relative one.

For example, running opensnoop.py and in another terminal running `cat anything.txt`, the output in opensnoop will show the relative filename, not an absolute path:

```
$ sudo ./venv/bin/python bcc/tools/opensnoop.py | grep anything.txt &

$ cat anything.txt 2>/dev/null
19536  cat                -1   2 anything.txt

$ cat /tmp/anything.txt 2>/dev/null
19540  cat                -1   2 /tmp/anything.txt
```

I've narrored down the code block in opensnoop.py that i should look into amending, and adding in some logic similar to:

```c
    // .. existing code
    bpf_probe_read_user(&data.fname, sizeof(data.fname), (void *)filename);
    data.id    = id;
    data.ts    = tsp / 1000;
    data.uid   = bpf_get_current_uid_gid();
    data.flags = flags; // EXTENDED_STRUCT_MEMBER
    data.ret   = ret;
    
    // new code to handle relative paths:
    if (data.fname[0] != '/' && data.fname[0] != '\\0') {
        // TODO if filename doesn't start with a /, need to convert relative path to abs
        struct fs_struct *fs = ((struct task_struct *) bpf_get_current_task())->fs;
        
        // TODO: get pwd path from fs->pwd
        struct path *pwd_path = &fs->pwd // ?

        // TODO: call bpf_d_path(pwd_path, buf, sz)

        // TODO: update data.fname to insert buf pwd)
    }

    events.perf_submit(ctx, &data, sizeof(data));
```

Where I'm stuck is the TODO parts, there doesn't seem to be many / any good examples of using the new `bpf_d_path` helper function

Comment: For what it's worth you have at least [one example](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e4d1af4b16f80a90d9cf3a09bee2012dcde45638) in the kernel's selftests.

Comment: @Qeole - Thanks for the link, unfortunately the tests show caling `get_d_path` when you have a file pointer - which isn't the case when open syscalls are made,